# cant get tweet on twitter with twitter4j since 15 June 2015

Tags: twitter4j

a week ago, I can get tweet and information users twitter using search and streams from twitter4j, but now can not took this data again. why? only out
"BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)"

Comment: sorry, i can get data with stream, buat i cant get data from search

Comment: i dont know why, but my source code is fix now. thanks